# Stop Visual Studio Code from automatically adding semicolons and single quotes in .ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Related [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122915/stop-visual-studio-code-from-automatically-adding-semicolons-in-vue-files) but different as for `.ts` files.  When using the QuickFix function to add a missing import I want it to use double quotes and stop it from ending with a semicolon to remain consistent with the existing code base.

I have disabled all extensions so I think this must be the built in Typescript formatting.  I have tried looking through the [visual studio code base](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/b819c7668ee0ebf2dfaee37b03e1810d072b0efc/extensions/typescript-language-features/src) and not found where this is being done yet.

Perhaps it is not possible to configure this using some setting in the preferences file?

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem. Have you tried starting Visual Studio Code with `code --disable-extensions`?

Comment: Yes, still have that behaviour with `code --disable-extensions`.  Am running version 1.36.1, yourself @grooveplex ?

Comment: Yeah, me too. Have you taken a look at your User Settings?

Comment: Yes though I just found `"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",` so that's good!  @grooveplex.  I was previously only looking under `"typescript.format....`  Over half way there :)  Only having to delete a semicolon is much less work than replacing single with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",` to your settings.json file for defaulting to double quotes.

Don't have a solution yet for not automatically inserting semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try these new settings (v1.41):

`javascript.format.semicolons`

`typescript.format.semicolons`

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#semicolon-formatter-options-for-javascript-and-typescript

Options are:

- `ignore` — Does not add or remove semicolons (default).
- `insert` — Insets
  semicolons at statement ends.
- `remove` — Remove unnecessary semicolons.