# How to add prettier config into eslint config?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

Note, I do not want semicolons used in my JS project.

[**YouTube video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfVPVmORnL4)

I tried disabling it in the .eslintrc.cjs file, however the strange thing is that `semi: 0` did not work to disable the warnings over missing `;`. However `semi: false` did disable the warnings in VScode.

However it seemed my problem was related to prettier, so I added the `prettier` config to my eslint file and used `semi: false` in there it worked. But when I run `npm run lint` I get the following error:

[image]

**My config**

```
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution")

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  rules: {
    semi: 0,
  },
  prettier: {
    rules: {
      semi: false
    },
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["cypress/e2e/**.{cy,spec}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      extends: ["plugin:cypress/recommended"],
    },
  ],
};
```

If I remove that prettier block note I will get the warnings again in my code:

[image]

My package.json file (created by Vue)

```
{
  "name": "moonholdings.xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173",
    "test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom",
    "test:e2e": "start-server-and-test preview http://127.0.0.1:4173/ 'cypress open --e2e'",
    "test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test preview http://127.0.0.1:4173/ 'cypress run --e2e'",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "eslint . && prettier --check ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^1.3.10",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress": "^10.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vitest": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.35.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check this library out [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint)

Comment: @orimdominic This is the package I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/eslint-config-prettier

Comment: Going to upload a YouTube video of my issue

Comment: In your prettier config, include the setting to not use semi colons https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#semicolons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to disable the **ESlint extension in VScode**, it was overriding my config files. Also this extension isn't needed.

[image]

Comment: I doubt. I use the VSCode Eslint extension but I don't use the VSCode extension for Prettier and it works fine with the config I suggested

Comment: Ah interesting, yeah I re-enabled it, also my Prettier is also disabled, and issue is still fixed. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Add "prettier/prettier" rule with prettier settings to your .eslintrc file:

```
"rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
              "trailingComma": "all",
              "tabWidth": 12,
              "semi": false,
              "singleQuote": true,
              "bracketSpacing": true,
              "eslintIntegration": true,
              "printWidth": 120
            }
          ]
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To help you better, please provide more details about your specific issue. Code snippets, error messages, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise questions get quicker and more accurate responses. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics, and I'll assist you further. For more information on how to write good answers check out: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)